# IIS Security Login Popup for one folder in server 2008

Tags: iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I am setting up a classic asp website on windows server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1. All my pages are working fine except for those in a single directory named /reports. That folder contains only .asp pages, no specialized config or hidden files.  Below is the image of the popup I get for that location.

[image]

In IIS I have Anonymous Authentication enabled and set to application pool, though I have also attempted setting it to IUSR which didn't change anything.

[image]

I went a bit nuts adding users with full control of the folder

[image]

If anyone has any ideas I am officially desperate. I've read and tried everything I can find on windows and stackoverflow websites.

Comment: I have not solved this, but I did work around the issue by copying to a new folder named reports2 which works perfectly?  Possibly something to do with the name of the folder?

Comment: If it's using the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account context, then you need to use `IIS_IUSRS` security group when applying permissions to the folder.

Comment: The very first thing you should do is to check what status/substatus code you got, and I wonder why "everything" does not include that.

Comment: @LexLi its Basic Authentication, as its at the login prompt the `Authorization` header hasn't been passed so the server must have return `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: What Identity is your Application Pool running as?

Comment: @Lankymart I did not have the IIS_IUSRS configured, but I added it and am still getting the same results.

Comment: @tom Jacob makes a good point, have you checked what account the Application Pool is using?

Comment: @JacobM. It is ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: Try changing that temporarily to one of the users who you've granted rights. I suspect that might be it.

Comment: @JacobM. not sure that is it. If the anonymous access user is set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, the Application Pool is running as `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and the folder has the appropriate rights for `IIS_IUSRS` it should work. So it is possibly a folder permission corruption problem *(try resetting the permissions by clearing them out and replacing)* or is it possibly Basic Authentication is enabled which is overriding the anonymous access?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) installed, the folder name "Reports" will be reserved. You can change the folder name "Reports" with something else in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager into Web Portal URL.